# Флаг -std=c++0x для nvcc

Tags: g++, cuda, c++

Всем привет! Подскажите чем можно заменить флаг `-std=c++0x` при компиляции или как-то программно его указать можно? С `g++` все работает на ура, а `nvcc` просто такой опции не распознает.

> nvcc fatal   : Unknown option 'std'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, правильно писать --compiler-options "-std=c++0x".
Во-вторых, nvcc не имеет поддержки C++11, поэтому совет из первого пункта не сработает.
Попробуйте убрать эту опцию и посмотрите, что получится. Если не скомпилируется – перепешите весь код использующий фичи из С++11 на С++98.

Comment: В части кода, которая компилируется для выполнения на GPU, поддержки С++ 11 действительно нет (пока, во всяком случае). Но для хостовой части почему ее не может быть?

Comment: Потому что парсер nvсс не переваривает конструкции из С++11.

Comment: nvcc это банально gcc с макросами, конекретно у меня nvcc компиляет и *cpp, *c, *cu ну и т.п. Кроме того в коде используется mpi, opencv, boost и непосредственно cuda, соответственно nvcc это спокойно собирает. А вот почему он не поддерживает столь простую опцию, это вопрос...

Comment: Нихрена ж себе *простая* опция.

Comment: Так и знал, что кто-то это напишет :) согласен, но все же.

Comment: Да, действительно, не кушает... Если очень хочется применить С++11 для хостовой части, в качестве противоядия могу предложить разделить программу на части и применить раздельную компиляцию модулей с последующей сборкой. Когда-то смешивал модули, скомпилированные nvcc, gcc и icpc.

Comment: @mikillskegg Расскажите, пожалуйста, поподробнее.

Comment: Чуть позже. Надо вспомнить. Давно это было...

Comment: Присоединяюсь. Интересно было бы посмотреть, а то все таки nvcc не охватывает все.

Comment: Если компилять так: --compiler-options "-std=c++0x", то заводится и в nvcc. Спасибо!

Comment: @Re1aps, тогда эту опцию скорре всего можно убрать совсем.